# Regex test number x number

Tags: php, regex

What regexp could I use to check where a string contains a `number x number`

For example:

```
TIM MIDLAND BLACK 21X8.5 5-128 ET16
```

How do I find out where is the `21X8?`

My purpose is to get the whole string until that

Comment: Can you provide multiple inputs and expected/desired outputs? What have you tried so far and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Input: TIM MIDLAND BLACK 21X8.5 5-128 ET16
Output: TIM MIDLAND BLACK

I have used this site: https://regexr.com/ but didn't find a solution

Comment: I just need the regex expression to find numberXnumber

Comment: @MaxExplode Well it's possible to be 
`TIM MIDLAND 5 BLACK 21X8.5 5-128 ET16 `

But I want to keep the `TIM MIDLAND 5 BLACK`

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty  of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.